# C++ value of the name of array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int foo[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    cout << (&foo[0]) << "   " << foo <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output result is 0x28feec    0x28feec.
What is the different between &foo[0], foo and &foo?
If foo is the pointer point to the address of foo[0], is it a good way to use it？

Thank you for answering.

Comment: It is also about [std::stream::operator <<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

Answer (score 2):

`foo` (without accessing an array element) will decay to the address of the first array element (`foo[0]`) when it is sent to the output stream.

`foo[0]` will return the first array element, and `&foo[0]` will decay to its address. Hence the two outputted values are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the type:

- `foo` has type `int(&)[5]`
- `foo[0]` has type `int&`
- `&foo` has type `int (*)[5]`
- `&foo[0]` has type `int*`

The `operator<<` doesn't accept references to arrays, so in `cout << foo` it will decay to a pointer, same as `&foo[0]`.  And `&foo` is a pointer to the same address.  But there's a big difference if you use `sizeof` or do pointer arithmetic, because then type matters.

For example:

```
(&foo[0]) + 1 == &foo[1]
```

but

```
(&foo)[1] == &foo[5]
```

Comment: @delnan: `foo + 1 != (&foo)[1]`, that's the difference I was talking about.  Clarified a little.